# Facebook API to search messages

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messages

I want to search facebook messages content using the graph API

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/threads?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

This one returns my facebook inbox messages, **Is** it possible to search for a specific word in those messages **using the API itself** without server side filtering ?, Just like how it works in the actual inbox, search feature lets me search in the message contents

Lets say this is a message : **" I love StackOverFlow users ! "**

I want to use something like this to only return it

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/threads?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&contains=stackoverflow
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use fql, example of search 'hi':

```
SELECT author_id, body, created_time FROM message WHERE thread_id IN (SELECT thread_id FROM thread WHERE folder_id = 0) AND CONTAINS("hi")
```

**Test with Graph API explorer**:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20author_id%2C%20body%2C%20created_time%20FROM%20message%20WHERE%20thread_id%20IN%20(SELECT%20thread_id%20FROM%20thread%20WHERE%20folder_id%20%3D%200)%20AND%20CONTAINS(%22hi%22)